# String to Long Results in Null Value

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a "**long**" value from a String containing a Facebook ID, which is a **10 digit number**. Here's what my function looks like:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
        try {
            final long opponentId;            
            opponentId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getLong("uid");
            String opponentName = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("name");
            Toast.makeText(this, "UID: " + opponentId + "\n" + "Name: " + opponentName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            String playerUidString = myPrefs.getString("uid", null);


            if (playerUidString == null) {
                Log.d(GlobalVars.TAG, "Empty UID");
                return;
            }

            Log.d(GlobalVars.TAG, "ID: " + playerUidString);
            Log.d(GlobalVars.TAG, "ID Long: " + String.valueOf(Long.getLong(playerUidString)));

//           long player_id = Long.getLong(playerUidString);
//          new GameRequest(getBaseContext(), player_id, opponentId);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(GlobalVars.TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Normally, I would set long player_id to equal the conversion of playerUidString to long, but Long.getLong(playerUidString) results in null, while playUidString equals the 10 digit ID number. Any reason why this is happening?

Edit: My Log.d outputs:

```
06-29 11:06:37.823: D/I See It(16053): ID: 1089490706
06-29 11:06:37.823: D/I See It(16053): ID Long: null
```

Comment: what are the outputs of the Log.d statements?  Are you sure of what playerUidString holds?

Comment: Maybe the JSONObject internally stores the id as a string and does not do an automatic conversion to long. You can verify that by looking at the original JSON string and look whether the id is enclosed in quotation marks. Other than that, just use Long.parseLong(playerUidString) and you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the fact that `Long.getLong(String str)` is not supposed to parse a String to a long, but rather to return a long value of a **system property** represented by that string. 
As others have suggested, what you actually need is `Long.parseLong(String str)`

[Check out Java Document Here for more information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#getLong%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks Android Coader, thats exactly what the problem was.

Comment: @user1000229 you welcome. I also gain knowledge from other and now try to share a little bit :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Long.parseLong(yourstring)

I hope I can helped you.